# Move UIScrollView so UIButton is fully shown

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have 6 UIButton controls placed inside a UIScrollView. 
The buttons are horizontally aligned, but there is only room for 3.5 of them to be visible at a time.

What I want to happen is when I touch the half visible button - for the UIScrollView to move its content so that the touched button will be fully visible (like how the filters bar works in Instagram).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
      [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:sender.frame animated:YES];
      //your code
}
```

Add action to button.

Comment: Works great! thank you! Is there a way to add some margin between the button and the scrollview edges?

Comment: sender.frame  =>  CGRectInset(sender.frame, -10, -10)